# Error: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'vInvReq.JDRF_Location__c' at line 16 column 13

Tags: apex-code

I am getting this error while compiling this trigger,
Error: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'vInvReq.JDRF_Location__c' at line 16 column 13
My code below, problem is with this line     `WHERE Name=vInvReq.JDRF_Location__c]);`
 Thanks and appreciate any help,

```
trigger TgrInventoryRequestAfter on Inventory_Request__c (after update) {

//set<Id> JDRFLocationId = new set<Id>();
//List<Inventory_Request__c> vLstInventory_Request= new List<Inventory_Request__c>();

List<JDRF_Location__c> locaList = new list<JDRF_Location__c>();

for (Inventory_Request__c vInvReq:trigger.new)
{


if(vInvReq.Request_Status__c == 'Approved' && vInvReq.Inventory_Type__c == 'Bag of Hope')
{
locaList=
 new list<JDRF_Location__c> ([Select Name,Current_boh_Inventory__c from JDRF_Location__c
  WHERE Name=vInvReq.JDRF_Location__c]);

  Integer sumCBOH = vInvReq.Units_Requested__c+ locaList.Current_boh_Inventory__c ;
  locaList.Current_boh_Inventory__c= sumCBOH;

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `=:` after `WHERE` in between the field name and the variable:

```
WHERE Name=:vInvReq.JDRF_Location__c
```

Here is why:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm